# How to select records in a delta table column in Azure Databricks with Map of Struct datatype?

Tags: arrays, struct, azure-databricks

I have a delta table in Databricks named `prod.silver.platform_ctl_ingestion`. It has a few columns including `table_name` with string data type and `transform_options` with below structure:

```
 |-- transform_options: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: struct (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- col_name_mappings: map (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- type_mappings: map (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- partition_duplicates_by: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- order_duplicates_by: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

For example, when `table_name` is `prod.silver.weather`, the `transform_options` is:

```
{
"prod.bronze.weather_source_a":{"col_name_mappings":{"col_a_old":"col_a_new","col_b_old":"col_b_new"},"type_mappings":{"col_a_new":"INT","col_b_new":"TIMESTAMP"},"partition_duplicates_by":["col_a_new"],"order_duplicates_by":["_commit_version"]},
"prod.bronze.weather_source_b":{"col_name_mappings":{"col_c_old":"col_c_new","col_d_old":"col_d_new"},"type_mappings":{"col_c_new":"INT","col_d_new":"TIMESTAMP"},"partition_duplicates_by":["col_c_new"],"order_duplicates_by":["ingestion_timestamp","_commit_version"]}
}
```

I want to select rows where `order_duplicates_by` in `transform_options` contains `_commit_version`.

I tried the below query but it returns all rows.

```
SELECT 
    *,
    transform_values(transform_options, (k, v) -> 
    CASE
    WHEN array_contains(v.order_duplicates_by, '_commit_version') THEN
    STRUCT(v.col_name_mappings, v.type_mappings, v.partition_duplicates_by, v.order_duplicates_by)
    ELSE NULL
    END
    ) AS updated_transform_options
FROM prod.silver.platform_ctl_ingestion;
```

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are filtering, then it will be easy to remove **`_commit_version`** in the array.

Command:

```sql
%sql
SELECT 
    *,
    transform_values(transform_options, (k, v) -> 
    STRUCT(v.col_name_mappings, v.type_mappings, v.partition_duplicates_by, array_append(array_remove(v.order_duplicates_by, '_commit_version'), 'commit_version') as order_duplicates_by)
    ) AS updated_transform_options
FROM control_table
WHERE array_contains(get(map_values(transform_options), 0)['order_duplicates_by'], '_commit_version');
```

No need to check **`_commit_version`** in `transform_values`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I just needed to revise WHERE clause by using Get() function to avoid error:  SELECT *
FROM dev.silver.test_silver_control_table
WHERE array_contains(
    get(map_values(transform_options), 0)['order_duplicates_by'],
    '_commit_version'
);

Comment: @Navven Sharma, I needed to change the code in the answer. That is why I didn't accept the answer. If the answer can be edited, I'll accept it then. Thanks.